# paypal extend authorization hold

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal Express checkout and able to make Authorization hold on Payers Card, but it expires after 29 days.

Can I extend the authorization period with Paypal Express Checkout API or Paypal Adaptive Payments API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DoReauthorization](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReauthorization_API_Operation_NVP/) to reauthorize an authorization and get more time.  What you may need to do is run the original Express Checkout as an order, which confirms the funds are available but actually doesn't place a hold.  Then within 29 days from that order being created you can authorize to actually hold the funds, but of course the authorization could fail at that point if the funds aren't available anymore (since they weren't held).

I know there are limitations with simply running an Authorization and DoReauthorization, but I'm having trouble tracking down the details in PayPal's new documentation.  If I remember correctly you can run DoReauthorization any time within the 29 days, but again, the funds still aren't guaranteed that point.  In fact, if I remember right, even a regular Authorization is only guaranteed for 3 days and you would need to run the reauth within that 3 days to buy an additional 3 days of guaranteed funds availability.

Outside of those 3 day periods the authorizations are good for 29 days, but it's possible funds aren't available.

If I can track down the details I'll post then.  They used to be in the detailed PDF documentation that PayPal had on their old site, but now they've moved all that to this new site with HTML docs and they're not as detailed.  Sort of frustrating.